# Fail on Character in RegEx expression

Tags: regex

I have an expression that works, except I want it to fail if it sees a ; anyplace other than the first character.  It works for (as desired)

```
; Person1: Role1,
```

but it also works for (not desired)

```
; Person1: Role1; Person2: Role2,
```

So, trying to figure out how to modify the following expression to fail on a semicolon after the first character (and actually the semicolon would only be found in the third group):

```
 (^|; )(.+?:)(.+?)(,)
```

Sorry, I don't know the flavor.  Usage is in an addon for a music tagging program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to allow a semicolon, then tell the regex engine so:

```
^;?\s*([^;:]+):\s*([^,;]+),$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
;?\s*    # Match optional ; and optional whitespace
([^;:]+) # Capture one or more characters except ; and : in group 1
:\s*     # Match : and optional whitespace
([^,;]+) # Capture one or more characters except , and ; in group 2
,        # Match ,
$        # End of string
```